# Is it possible to modify mapping for @Column() during runtime?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have some entity mapped to a sql view as

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "SOME_VIEW")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "SOME_COL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Integer id;
 ...
}
```

Today I was told that on one of servers, column `SOME_COL` in `SOME_VIEW` will be filled with nulls, and I should use `SOME_OTHER_COL` as id, depending on value in `config.properties` file.
Since `@Column` has `@Retention(RUNTIME)`, might it be possible that I can change mapping to `@Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_COL")` before application starts on tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not "fool" hibernate with substitution, even with javassist or asm help (without heavy headache and with them too). I see several ways to solve your problem:

1. Try to understand, why primary key column has nulls and correct them.
2. Divide code into two branch, and build packages specified for every server.
3. Find natural key and use EmbeddedId.